# Copy huge amount from 1 table to other

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance, bulkcopy, query-performance

I have two tables with same structure I need to copy over all tables from table A to table B, the problem is that some records from table A already exist in table B so that made the Import Fail.

So I made a query to do the import (Also using the build in Import tool) like that

```
SELECT * from TransactionEntryN
WHERE TransactionEntryN.TransactionEntryID 
NOT IN (select TransactionEntryID FROM TransactionEntry)
```

The problem is that this operation takes 13 min. to copy just 50K records and I have 16 Million records there, it would take me a week to finish that...

Is there any faster way to do it?

btw the primary key TransactionEntryID is a uniqueidentifier that may slow it down? (I can't change it I'm just wondering if that the issue.

Comment: Try where not exists and make sure the TransactionEntryID is indexed in both tables.

Comment: "all tables from table A to table B"?

Comment: yes, but only if there's not the same record already there (since I copied some already and other records where added to table B since.)

Comment: No there not indexed, should I add a clustered or a non clustred index?

Comment: I won't put this as an answer but just a suggestion for you: Since I'm reading that you need to merge datasets (possibly in both directions if records are missing on either side?) you could consider a tool like Redgate's data compare. For a dataset that large you'd probably need a large temp area for the util if you went that way, but it does simplify tasks like this if you don't want to or don't have the time to work out the T-SQL. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I have red gate installed on this server I couldn't figure out how to make use of it solvoing this problem.

Comment: Confine the compare to one table at a time with a dataset that large. Then you can choose to let Redgate do the updating for you, or tell it to build a script for the updating. Make sure to check the compare options carefully so that you're accomplishing what you intend. I like the Redgate DDL & DML compare tools, they save a lot of time. (No I don't work for them)

Comment: You could also consider SQL Server Merge replication to keep both sides in sync going forward once you've got them synced up. Since you've said the structures are identical this could work out very well for you depending on the volume of updates you need to account for.

Comment: That's a one time thing. I won't need to do it again.

Comment: I'd def use Redgate then since it's a 1 time thing & you won't need to reuse the T-SQL. Once you have the options set how you want "press play" :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2859/discussion-between-ezi-and-eric-higgins)

Comment: Would like to chat but can't, it's blocked due to compliance reqs.

Comment: its ok with me.

Comment: AFAIK Data compare pulls all data to the client for comparison. As such, it is not fast for larger tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the second table to contain the same data as the first table, why not simply wipe the table out and replace it?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  DROP TABLE TransactionEntry;

  SELECT * INTO dbo.TransactionEntry FROM dbo.TransactionEntryN
    -- other WHERE clauses?
  ;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
-- create indexes / permissions etc.
```

Comment: the problem is that some records where added already in table B that are not in table A so this option is not available anymore... its too late

Comment: Maybe you could isolate those rows and store them elsewhere first? This is probably still most efficient if it is a small number.

Comment: sounds like this would be my best (only) solution

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the rows that are in table B and not in table A. Then you could use DOTNET SQLBulkCopy to copy data from table A to table B. It is pretty fast. For 100,000 records it would take less than 10 seconds. I am writing some pseudo code here. If you want a complete working example you could go to http://technico.qnownow.com/2012/03/27/using-sql-bulk-copy-to-efficiently-load-data-from-source-db-to-destination-db/

```
// Open a sourceConnection
        using (SqlConnection sourceConnection =
                   new SqlConnection(GetSourceConnectionString()))
        {
            sourceConnection.Open();

            // Get the data from the source table as a SqlDataReader.
            SqlCommand commandSourceData = new SqlCommand(
                @"SELECT *                   
                FROM dbo.tableA;", sourceConnection);
            SqlDataReader reader =
                commandSourceData.ExecuteReader();

             // Open the destination connection. 
            using (SqlConnection destinationConnection =
                       new SqlConnection(GetDestinationConnectionString()))
            {
                destinationConnection.Open();

                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                           new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName =
                        "dbo.tableB";

                    try
                    {                            
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                    }
                    finally
                    {                            
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Getting all that data over the network to the client and back to the server in inefficient.